# Index out of range in leetcode ide in code for finding the length of the longest substring without repeating characters

Tags: python-3.x

This below giving expected output in pycharm and the other side it's getting index out of range in line `return length_of_substring[-1]` in leetcode.

why it is getting such error?

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, string):
        unique_list = []
        length_of_substring = []

        for i in string:
            if i not in unique_list:
                unique_list.append(i)


            else:
                length_of_substring.append(len(unique_list))

                unique_list.clear()
                unique_list.append(i)
        length_of_substring.sort()

        return length_of_substring[-1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    obj = Solution()
    result = Solution.lengthOfLongestSubstring(obj, s)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: when posting here you should clearly specify (i) the goal of your code and (ii) a self contained minimum example.

In your case it is very difficult to answer your question, because you do not make clear what your code is actually trying to achieve.

**Regarding your error message**:

Your code does not account for the fact that a string could also consist of only unique elements (e.g. "abcd"). In that case the `else` clause of your code is never reached and `length_of_substring` will remain empty. If you then call `length_of_substring[-1]` it raises an error message.